# Fast/easy renaming of filenames in TFS (CodePlex)

Tags: version-control, tfs, codeplex, file-rename

I host a project on CodePlex, but a bunch (200+) files need to have their extension changed.

What is the easiest, least painful way to do this?  I cant see myself doing them one by one in the IDE.

**Update:**

I know I can just remove and change them via the commandline/utility, and readd them, but that would lose history.

Perhaps there is some commandline interface to TFS on CodePlex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [tf.exe](http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlex/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Obtaining%20the%20Team%20Explorer%20Client&referringTitle=CodePlex%20FAQ) which is installed with TFS Team Explorer. See

```
tf.exe rename /?
```

for help. Hint: You have to use the /login parameter to specify your credentials. Without that tf.exe uses your windows account. A rename could then be like this:

```
tf rename /login:user,password old.cs new.cs
```